# AuthenticationTokenProvider: Custom error message

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I have implemented my own `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` and `AuthenticationTokenProvider` and everything works fine however I would like to send error message with a little bit more details.
At the moment when something goes wrong with my refresh token I receive the following JSON object: `{"error":"invalid_grant"}` 
What I'd like is something like
`{"error":"invalid_grant","reason":"here_goes_my_custom_message"}`.

It can easily be done in the `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider` (say in `GrantResourceOwnerCredentials` method) as the context in parameter inherit from `BaseValidatingContext` therefore I can use:

```
if (user == null)
{
   context.Rejected();
   context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
   return;
}
```

However I don't know how to do something similar in my `AuthenticationTokenProvider`. I have the following method:

```
public async Task ReceiveAsync(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
    {
        string hashedTokenId = Helper.GetHash(context.Token);
        OAuthRefreshToken refreshToken = _oAuthRefreshTokenService.FindRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);

        if (refreshToken != null)
        {
            //Get protectedTicket from refreshToken class
            context.DeserializeTicket(refreshToken.ProtectedTicket);
            var result = _oAuthRefreshTokenService.RemoveRefreshToken(hashedTokenId);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** The `AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext` is not a `BaseValidatingContext` and therefore doen't have the `SetError` or `Rejected` methods.

And I want to return a custom error message when my refresh token is `null`. Any idea how?

Comment: You can't: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725791/override-error-code-on-authorizationcodeprovider-create/31746935#31746935.

Answer (score 1):

It may be late as an answer for the OP, but I've just solved this issue and I'll write the answer here hoping others will find it:

The method where a Refresh token cand be rejected is `GrantRefreshToken` from `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`. This method is called after the authorization context was created by the `AuthenticationTokenProvider`

```
// this is caleld after AuthenticationTokenProvider.Receive

public override Task GrantRefreshToken(OAuthGrantRefreshTokenContext context)
{
    base.GrantRefreshToken(context);
    if (UserLocked(context.Ticket.Identity))
    {
        context.Rejected();
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "User is locked", "usr-lockout");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

A minor change in your code is required to see the `response.data.error` and `response.data.error_description` properties in a JSON object:

```
if(user == null) {
    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
    return;
}
```

Comment: One of the issues with SO is people throwing trivial answers without trying to understand what the problem really is.

Let me detail what you should have read between the lines: AFAIK, the SetError method is only available if the context inherits from BaseValidatingContext as mentioned in my question. 
The context in my method is an AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext that only inherits from BaseContext not BaseValidatingContext. As a consequence the method SetError is not available hence my question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851802/how-to-set-error-in-authenticationtokencreatecontext