# How to set error in AuthenticationTokenCreateContext?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0

I have to set error in AuthenticationTokenCreateContext.

Its possible to set error in OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext by using context.SetError().

But in AuthenticationTokenCreateContext there is no context.SetError().

How can i set error in AuthenticationTokenCreateContext?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to finish the function flow with `return;` without calling the `context.SetToken()`. Thus, the `context.Token` property is not set and is not sent to the client.

**EDIT**

See comments and chat for a full explanation of the solution.

Comment: Ok. But i have to send some error message to client.

Comment: This is managed by the `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth` dll. You can see in [`OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler`](https://github.com/yreynhout/katana-clone/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth/OAuthAuthorizationServerHandler.cs) and you cannot override this behaviour. Which token provider are you implementing?

Comment: private void ReceiveAccessToken(AuthenticationTokenReceiveContext context)
        {}

Comment: Ok, you are implementing an `AccesTokenProvider`, then, if you find an error deserializing the authentication ticket in the token or validating any claim in the ticket or whatever, you can break the flow and return an error setting the `context.Response.StatusCode` and the `context.Response.ReasonPhrase` properties, for example `context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;`and `context.Response.ReasonPhrase = "You don't have permission to access to the url you are trying.";`.

Comment: See the `Status` field in the top-right of the Postman response, next to the `Time` label. For the proposed example I'm receiving `Status: 403 You don't have permission to access to the url you are trying.`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114927/discussion-between-karthikeyan-and-jumuro).

Comment: @Karthikeyan - it would be nice when you finish your conversation you post your results to this SO question so other users can benefit from your discoveries....